# How to fixed erlang unmet dependancy on ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, erlang

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove erlang
```

and for other package like for node

Error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rabbitmq-server : Depends: erlang-base (>= 1:19.3) but 1:18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3.1 is to be installed or
                            erlang-base-hipe (>= 1:19.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:19.3)
                   Depends: erlang-crypto (>= 1:19.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:19.3)
                   Depends: erlang-eldap (>= 1:19.3) but 1:18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3.1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:19.3)
                   Depends: erlang-inets (>= 1:19.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:19.3)
                   Depends: erlang-mnesia (>= 1:19.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:19.3)
                   Depends: erlang-os-mon (>= 1:19.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:19.3)
                   Depends: erlang-parsetools (>= 1:19.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:19.3)
                   Depends: erlang-public-key (>= 1:19.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:19.3)
                   Depends: erlang-runtime-tools (>= 1:19.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:19.3)
                   Depends: erlang-ssl (>= 1:19.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:19.3)
                   Depends: erlang-syntax-tools (>= 1:19.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:19.3)
                   Depends: erlang-tools (>= 1:19.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:19.3)
                   Depends: erlang-xmerl (>= 1:19.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:19.3)
                   Depends: socat but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: No, I thought it will break my system. Is it safe to run ?

Comment: Why should it and if it does then the dependencies won't ever be met!

Comment: Looks like a classic case of wrong-version source. Please edit your question to include the complete output of `apt-cache policy rabbitmq-server`, and please tell us which release of Ubuntu you are running.

Answer (score 2):

I got same error after installing old `elixir` and then manually adding the latest erlang repo on their website. Deleting the old version helped me:

```bsh
sudo apt-get purge elixir
sudo apt-get purge erlang
```

After the purge, I could successfully install the:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install esl-erlang
```